# ListView's SelectedIndexChanging event inside an UpdatePanel causes a whole page reloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a ListView that's inside a UpdatePanel, UpdateMode = Conditional:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListView ID="SearchListView" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div id="scrollDiv" onscroll="SaveScrollPosition();">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                    ...
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblUnitItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <SelectedItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblUnitItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </SelectedItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Selecting a list item cause the whole page reloading instead of partial page refresh.
I bound the listview to the datasource in the method "FillSearchListView", and implemented the "OnSearchListViewItemCommand" and "OnSearchListViewSelectedIndexChanging" events:

```
protected void OnSearchListViewSelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
    FillSearchListView();
}

protected void OnSearchListViewItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "Select":
            ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
            this.CurrentId = decimal.Parse((string)e.CommandArgument);
            break;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: Which partial should be refreshed?

Comment: I meant that i don't want the whole page refresh while clicking on a list item.

Comment: And you dont have to but what part of thee page has to be updated?

Comment: There is a form view next to the list view, whice changes its content according to the selected list item

Answer (score 2):

In the new version of ASP.NET changes the ID generation of a control inside a container like ListView.
Triggers on UpdatePanel doesn't work for fix this.

Simply **put ClientIDMode="AutoID" in your linkbuttons** (or another control), so the postback will be async.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use triggering in the update panel

here is the code

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:ListView ID="SearchListView" runat="server">
                                        <LayoutTemplate>
                                             </LayoutTemplate> 
                                        </asp:ListView> 
                                    </ContentTemplate> 
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchListView" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute: ChildrenAsTriggers="true"

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"   ChildrenAsTriggers="true" >
```

See childerenastriggers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListView ID="SearchListView" runat="server">
                        <LayoutTemplate>
                            <div id="scrollDiv" onscroll="SaveScrollPosition();">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        ...
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </LayoutTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblUnitItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <SelectedItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lblUnitItem" runat="server" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </SelectedItemTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchListView" EventName="SelectedIndexChanging" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SearchListView" EventName="ItemCommand" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```